# Subharmonic function and holomorphically parametrized integrals

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

Let $f_\lambda$ be a family of $L^1$ functions (say on $\mathbb{C}$) such that for all $z$ the map $\lambda \mapsto f_\lambda(z)$ is holomorphic.

Consider the map $N(\lambda)=\log \int |f_\lambda(z)| dm(z)$.
Is $N$ subhmarmonic ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Pass from finite sums to the integral in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/794773/

Comment: @wordsthatendinGRY   but is it clear that passing to this limit (replacing finite sums by integrals) is preserving subharmonicity ? you only have a punctual convergence, right ?

Comment: OK, that looks tedious. A quick way is to use the integral characterization of log-subharmonicity due to Beckenbach and Rado: [slide 4 here](http://math.uark.edu/SLS-10-Marola.pdf). When you integrate with respect to parameter $z$, the right hand side adds up, while the left side is subadditive due to Minkowski's inequality. Yes, there should be a more direct proof...

Comment: But a more direct proof is likely to be painful. In [Corollary 2.4 here](http://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4260) the authors state the result for integrals of LSH functions, but with  additional continuity hypotheses. Then they discuss how the hypotheses might have been removed, but they don't want to work that hard...